# What is the technical name for the “time boxes” on an instrument approach plate?

Tags: faa, aeronautical-charts, instrument-procedures

Some instrument approach plates include a list of groundspeeds and times from the FAF to the MAP. What is the real name for these time boxes?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/flying/comments/8ienph/instrument_rating_donezo_checkride_writeup/dyrb9qb/ Related question, eh? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [FAA Aeronautical Chart User’s Guide for Terminal Procedure Publications](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/media/editions/cug-tpp-edition.pdf), in the revision effective 29 March 2018 on [pages 30 and 31](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/media/editions/cug-tpp-edition.pdf#page=30), it is a *Time/Distance Table*.

> **Time/Distance Table**
>
> When applicable, a Time/Distance Table is provided below the airport sketch. The table provides the distance and time
>   that is required from the final approach fix to the missed approach point for select groundspeeds.
>
> [image: “Time boxes” below the airport sketch]